# Como Sincronizar Sqlite con Webservices Ksoap

Tags: android, android-sqlite, webservice, ksoap

Tengo mi app la cual la tengo para que trabaje en modo desconectado del wifi o datos, el cual todo las aplicaciones de pago que se realizan las guardo en una bd sqlite, para despues cuando el usuario tenga acceso a internete sincronize esos los datos modficados los mande conectando al webservices ksoap y se guarden en mi bd sql

Lo que necesito Hacer, es primero tener un boton de sincronizar, que cuando se de click se revise en mi bd sqlite si tengo registros afectados, y si tengo haga el llamado al webservices a los metodos que tengo para grabar y mandar los datos afectados

Ahorita ya tengo un boton de sincronizar, en el cual yo mando a llamar mis metodos de donde obtengo la informacion para guardarlo en mi bd.

Les dejo mi codigo

Clase donde mando a llamar mi webservices y lleno mi bd sqlite

```
public class webServiceSincro {

private String ONControlWSURL;
private String ONControlWSNameSpace;
private String ONControlToken;
private int ONControlZonaCliente = 0;
private int ONControlEmpresa;
private String ONControlUsuario;


public webServiceSincro(String ONControlWSURL,
                        int ONControlZonaCliente,
                        String ONControlToken,
                        int ONControlEmpresa,
                        String ONControlUsuario)
{

    this.ONControlUsuario = ONControlUsuario;
    this.ONControlEmpresa = ONControlEmpresa;
    this.ONControlToken = ONControlToken;
    this.ONControlZonaCliente = ONControlZonaCliente;
    this.ONControlWSNameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";
    this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL + "/ONControl_MobileWSCore.asmx";
}


public class STR_ResultadoSincro
{
    Integer ErrorId=1;
    Integer UltimoId=0;
    String Mensaje="";
    Integer PrimerId=0;
    String Folio="";
    String ErrorCone="";
    ArrayList MenuArray;
    Integer Empresa=0;
    String UserName = "";
    String Token = "";
    Boolean Valido;
    ArrayList ClienteArray;
    ArrayList DetalleArray;

}

public STR_ResultadoSincro Menu()
{
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ONControlWSNameSpace, "Menu");
    request.addProperty("Empresa", ONControlEmpresa);
    request.addProperty("Token", ONControlToken);
    // Property which holds input parameters

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = false;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ONControlWSURL, 7000);

    STR_ResultadoSincro O_Resultado = new STR_ResultadoSincro();


    //ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(ONControlWSNameSpace+"Menu", envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        O_Resultado.ErrorId= Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        O_Resultado.UltimoId= Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(1).toString());
        O_Resultado.Mensaje= String.valueOf(response.getProperty(2));

        SoapObject SO_Menu = (SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(3)).getProperty(1)).getProperty(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < SO_Menu.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

            Menu.oBD.InsertarMenu(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Id",(SoapObject) SO_Menu.getProperty(i))),
                                              ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Empresa", (SoapObject)SO_Menu.getProperty(i))),
                                              webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Descripcion", (SoapObject) SO_Menu.getProperty(i)),
                                              webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Evento", (SoapObject) SO_Menu.getProperty(i)),
                                              ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Modulo", (SoapObject)SO_Menu.getProperty(i))),
                                              ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Operacion",(SoapObject)SO_Menu.getProperty(i))),
                                              ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webServiceSincro.WSGetPropertyNull("Documento", (SoapObject)SO_Menu.getProperty(i))));


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        //menu.errored = true;
        O_Resultado.ErrorCone = String.valueOf(e);
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    //return loginStatus;


    return O_Resultado;
}
```

Clase de mi bd sqlite

```
public class SqliteDB {


SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String onc_settings, int i) {
    return null;
}

private DBhelper oBD;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public SqliteDB(Context context)
{
    oBD = new DBhelper(context);
}

public void CloseDB()
{
    if (db.isOpen())
    {
        db.close();
    }
}

public boolean isOpenDB()
{
    return(db.isOpen());
}

public long executeSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
{
    long iRet = 0;
    db = oBD.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(sql, bindArgs);
    CloseDB();
    return(iRet);
}

public Cursor querySql(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    Cursor oRet = null;
    db = oBD.getReadableDatabase();
    oRet = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    return (oRet);
}


//Metodos Insert

public void InsertarCXCPEncabezado(int Empresa,
                                   int Cliente,
                                   String ClienteClave,
                                   String ClienteDescripcion,
                                   String ClienteDatosGenerales,
                                   int Moneda,
                                   int Zona,
                                   String ZonaClave,
                                   String ZonaDescripcion,
                                  double Saldo,
                                  double SaldoVencido
)
{
    Object[] CXCPEncabezado = {Empresa,Cliente,ClienteClave,ClienteDescripcion,ClienteDatosGenerales,Moneda,Zona,ZonaClave,ZonaDescripcion,Saldo,SaldoVencido};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", CXCPEncabezado );

}


public void InsertarCXCPDetalle(
        int Id,
        String Folio,
        //Date Fecha,
        int Documento,
        String DocumentoDescripcion,
        int Cliente,
        int Moneda,
        double Importe,
        double Descuento,
        double SubTotal,
        double Retencion1,
        double Retencion2,
        double IEPS,
        double IVA,
        double Total,
        double Saldo,
        double SaldoVencido,
        String Parcialidad,
        double ParcialidadTotal,
        String PagoCondicionDescripcion,
        String UltimoCobroObservacion
)
{
    Object [] CXCPDetalle = {Id,
                          Folio,
                         // Fecha,
                          Documento,
                          DocumentoDescripcion,
                          Cliente,
                          Moneda,
                          Importe,
                          Descuento,
                          SubTotal,
                          Retencion1,
                          Retencion2,
                          IEPS,
                          IVA,
                          Total,
                          Saldo,
                          SaldoVencido,
                          Parcialidad,
                          ParcialidadTotal,
                          PagoCondicionDescripcion,
                          UltimoCobroObservacion};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA + " Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", CXCPDetalle);
}

public void InsertarZona(
                         int Id,
                         String Clave,
                         String Descripcion)
{
    Object [] Zona = {Id,Clave,Descripcion};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Zona + " VALUES(?,?,?)", Zona );
}

public void InsertarEmpresa(
        int Id,
        String Clave,
        String Descripcion)
{
    Object [] Empresa = {Id,Clave,Descripcion};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Empresa + " VALUES(?,?,?)", Empresa );
}


public void InsertarPagoForma(int Id,
                               String Clave,
                               String Descripcion)
{
    Object [] PagoForma = {Id,Clave,Descripcion};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_FormaPago + " VALUES(?,?,?)", PagoForma );
}


public void InsertarMenu(int Id,
                         int Empresa,
                         String Descripcion,
                         String Evento,
                         int Modulo,
                         int Operacion,
                         int Documento)
{
    Object [] Menu = {Id,Empresa,Descripcion,Evento,Modulo,Operacion,Documento};
    executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Menu + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", Menu );
}

//Metodos Selects

public ArrayList<DetalleMenu> ObtenerMenu()
{
    ArrayList<DetalleMenu> ArrayMenu = new ArrayList<DetalleMenu>();
    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Menu , null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0) {

        while (aRS.moveToNext()) {

            DetalleMenu newDetalle = new DetalleMenu(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IdMenu))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_EmpresaM))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionMenu))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Evento))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Modulo))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Operacion))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLIMN_NAME_Documento))));
            ArrayMenu.add(newDetalle);
        }

    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayMenu;
}


public ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ObtenerClientes()
{
    ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> resultList = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();
    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME , null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0) {

        while (aRS.moveToNext()) {

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor ob = new CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido))));
            resultList.add(ob);
        }

    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return resultList;
}

public ArrayList<Zona> ObtenerZonas()
{
    ArrayList<Zona> ArrayZona = new ArrayList<Zona>();
    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Zona , null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0) {

        while (aRS.moveToNext()) {

            Zona newDetalle = new Zona(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Zona))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Clave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionZona))));
            ArrayZona.add(newDetalle);
        }

    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayZona;
}

public ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ObtenerClienteZona()

{

    ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> ArrayClienteZona = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();

    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona + " = " + settings.getInt("ONControlZonaCliente",0) ,null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0){

        while (aRS.moveToNext()){

            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor newdetalle = new CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda))),
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaClave))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaDescripcion))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo))),
                    (aRS.getDouble(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido))));
            ArrayClienteZona.add(newdetalle);

        }
    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayClienteZona;
}


public ArrayList<Empresa> ObtenerEmpresa()
{
    ArrayList<Empresa> ArrayEmpresa = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Empresa , null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0) {

        while (aRS.moveToNext()) {

            Empresa newDetalle = new Empresa(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Empresa))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClaveEmpresa))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionEmpresa))));
            ArrayEmpresa.add(newDetalle);
        }

    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayEmpresa;
}


public ArrayList<FormaPago> ObtenerPagoForma()
{
    ArrayList<FormaPago> ArrayPagoForma = new ArrayList<FormaPago>();
    Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_FormaPago , null);
    if (aRS.getCount() > 0) {

        while (aRS.moveToNext()) {

            FormaPago newDetalle = new FormaPago(
                    (aRS.getInt(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Empresa))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClaveEmpresa))),
                    (aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionEmpresa))));
            ArrayPagoForma.add(newDetalle);
        }

    }
    aRS.close();
    CloseDB();
    return ArrayPagoForma;
}



public ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ObtenerCXCPDetalle() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ArrayDetalle = new ArrayList<CXCPDetalle>();
    Cursor aRs = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA + " WHERE " + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente + " = " + 15  , null);
    if (aRs.getCount() > 0){
        while (aRs.moveToNext())
        {
            CXCPDetalle detalleCxP = new CXCPDetalle(
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Folio))),
                   // (DateFormatter.parse(aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Fecha)))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Documento))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DocumentoDescripcion))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente))),
                    (aRs.getInt(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_MOneda))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Importe))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Descuento))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IEPS))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IVA))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SAldo))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldovencido))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Parcialidad))),
                    (aRs.getDouble(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ParcialidadTotal))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_PagoCondicionDescripcion))),
                    (aRs.getString(aRs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_UltimoCobroObservacion))));
            ArrayDetalle.add(detalleCxP);
        }
    }

    return ArrayDetalle;
}




public static class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DBManager";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ONC_Mobile.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 11;

    //TablaCliente
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CXCPSaldoDocumentoEncabezado";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Empresa = "Empresa";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Cliente = "Cliente";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave = "ClienteClave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion = "ClienteDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales = "ClienteDatosGenerales";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Moneda = "Moneda";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Zona = "Zona";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ZonaClave = "ZonaClave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ZonaDescripcion = "ZonaDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Saldo = "Saldo";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido = "SaldoVencido";

    //Table DetalleCliente
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_DETA = "CXCPSaldoDocumentoDetalle";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "Id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Folio = "Folio";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Fecha = "Fecha";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Documento = "Documento";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DocumentoDescripcion = "DocumentoDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CLiente = "CLiente";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MOneda = "Moneda";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Importe = "Importe";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Descuento = "Descuento";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal = "SubTotal";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1 = "Retencion1";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2 = "Retencion2";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IEPS = "IEPS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IVA = "IVA";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Total = "Total";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SAldo = "Saldo";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Saldovencido = "SaldoVencido";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Parcialidad = "Parcialidad";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ParcialidadTotal = "ParcialidadTotal";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PagoCondicionDescripcion = "PagoCondicionDescripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_UltimoCobroObservacion = "UltimoCobroObservacion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Status = "Status";

    //Tabla ZonaZliente

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_Zona = "Zona";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID_Zona = "Id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Clave = "Clave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionZona = "Descripcion";

    //Tabla FormaPago
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_FormaPago = "PagoForma";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID_Forma = "Id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClaveForma = "Clave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionForma = "Descripcion";

    // Tabla Empresa
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_Empresa = "Empresa";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID_Empresa = "Id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClaveEmpresa = "Clave";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionEmpresa = "Descripcion";

    //Tabla Menu
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_Menu = "Menu";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_IdMenu = "Id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_EmpresaM = "Empresa";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionMenu = "Descripcion";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Evento = "Evento";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Modulo = "Modulo";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Operacion = "Operacion";
    public static final String COLIMN_NAME_Documento = "Documento";




    //Se Crea Tabla de Cliente
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w("[CHECK]", "DBHelper.onCreate....");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Zona + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaClave + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ZonaDescripcion + " TEXT ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido + " DOUBLE "
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Zona + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Clave + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionZona + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                + ");");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_FormaPago + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Forma + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClaveForma + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionForma + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                + ");");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Empresa + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Empresa + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClaveEmpresa + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionEmpresa + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Menu + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IdMenu + " INTEGER  ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_EmpresaM + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DescripcionMenu + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Evento + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Modulo + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Operacion + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLIMN_NAME_Documento + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA + "("
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID_Zona + " INTEGER  ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Folio + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
               // + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Fecha + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Documento + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_DocumentoDescripcion + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_MOneda + " INTEGER ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Importe + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Descuento + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SubTotal + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion1 + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Retencion2 + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IEPS + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_IVA + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Total + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SAldo + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldovencido + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Parcialidad + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ParcialidadTotal + " DOUBLE ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_PagoCondicionDescripcion + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_UltimoCobroObservacion + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Status + " "
                + ");");



    }






    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Actualizacion de BDD de la version " + oldVersion + " a la "
                + newVersion + ", de la que se destruira la informacion anterior");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Zona);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_FormaPago);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Empresa);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_Menu);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA);

        onCreate(db);
    }
    DBhelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Aclaro el llamado lo realizo en segundo plano usando Asynctask

Comment: Si te puedes explicar mucho mejor tanto tu problema y que es lo que quieres y aparte muestras el código que tienes es mas probable que alguien te haga caso...

Comment: ok, voy a actualiza mi post

Comment: Listo ya actualize

Comment: No te seria más fácil implementarlo con firebase? lo digo porque he leido que lo hace de forma nativa, si está offline vas trabajando y cuando detecta internet sincroniza los datos.

Comment: No conozco esa herramienta @Webservices

Comment: En lugar de trabajar con Sqlite?